# How to bind checkBox to a boolean property?

Tags: java, checkbox, vaadin, vaadin7

I started using vaadin framework recently.

I have a Form which contains some textFields and a checkbox, my problem is all fields are binding with their properties expect checkbox ??.

This is the form :

```
public class ContactForm extends FormLayout {

private Button save = new Button("Save", this::save);
private Button delete = new Button("Delete", this::delete);
private Button cancel = new Button("Cancel", this::cancel);
private TextField firstName = new TextField("First name");
private TextField lastName = new TextField("Last name");
private TextField phone = new TextField("Phone");
private TextField email = new TextField("Email");
private DateField birthDate = new DateField("Birth date");
private CheckBox bookMarks = new CheckBox("BookMarks");

private Contact contact;

// Easily bind forms to beans and manage validation and buffering
private BeanFieldGroup<Contact> formFieldBindings;

public ContactForm() {
    configureComponents();
    buildLayout();
}

private void configureComponents() {...}

private void buildLayout() {...}



void edit(Contact contact) {

    this.contact = contact;
    if (contact != null) {
        // Bind the properties of the contact POJO to fields in this form
        formFieldBindings = BeanFieldGroup.bindFieldsBuffered(contact, this);

        delete.setVisible(contact.getId() != null);
    }

    setVisible(contact != null);
}

@Override
public AddressbookUI getUI() {
    return (AddressbookUI) super.getUI();
}}
```

This is My class Contact :

```
public class Contact implements Serializable, Cloneable {

private Long id;

private String firstName = "";
private String lastName = "";
private String phone = "";
private String email = "";
private Date birthDate;
private Boolean bookMarks;

// getters and setters
...
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Should I bind the checkbox field manually ?

Comment: yeah, When I check the checkbox and save the form nothing happens

Comment: `(Boolean) bookMarks .getValue()` will help you to get the value

Comment: I think I should add a listener to checkbox, but I don't know how to do it !! @soorapadman what do you think ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add `addValueChangeListener` to the check box like this :

```
bookMarks.addValueChangeListener(event -> contact.setBookMarks(bookMarks.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of `check box` value `onlistenter` and set the object explicitly.

```
bookMarks.addListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

        contact.setBookMarks(checkbox1.getValue());
    }
});
```

To Know more about checkbox check this [link](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/components.checkbox.html)

Comment: I'm using vaddin 7, this code works only on vaadin 6, anyway It helps me thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the formFieldBindings BeanFieldGroup you've created. So change this line

```
 formFieldBindings = BeanFieldGroup.bindFieldsBuffered(contact, this);
```

to

```
 formFieldBindings = new BeanFieldGroup<Contact>(Contact.class);
 formFieldBindings.setItemDataSource(contact);
 formFieldBindings.buildAndBindMemberFields(this);
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but doesn't workthe checkbox still not binding. But If I add a listener to it it works.

Comment: It might be worth changing your bean to use the primitive boolean. That may be why it's not binding correctly.

Comment: The problem comes from the CheckBox component, I already used primitive boolean but in vain.